# NetSuite Case statement works in Saved Search but doesn't work in Workflow

Tags: sql, oracle, workflow, netsuite

I have an issue with a formula case statement in a NetSuite workflow, I am using the same case statement in a saved search and it works just fine, but generates an error in the workflow formula for sourcing date, to set the date field on a cashsale record created from a sales order.

NetSuite formula which basically states if it is 10:00 PM (22:00) or after increment by one day, otherwise use datecreated date. (this is used to calculate settlement date for banking reconciliation matching)

The workflow event is "Before Record Load" on "Create" a Cashsale record which is definitely a server-side event. I have also independently pulled out

```
to_date({createdfrom.datecreated}) + 1
```

and

```
{createdfrom.datecreated}
```

Which work independently as expected without errors, really not sure what I am doing wrong

```
CASE WHEN to_number(to_char({createdfrom.datecreated}, 'HH24')) >= 22 THEN to_date({createdfrom.datecreated}) + 1 ELSE {createdfrom.datecreated} END
```

Here is the case statement I used in my saved search which works perfectly

```
CASE WHEN to_number(to_char({datecreated}, 'HH24')) >= 22 THEN to_char(({datecreated} + 1), 'DD/MM/YYYY') ELSE to_char(({datecreated}), 'DD/MM/YYYY') END
```

Comment: Some fields are not filled in until a record is saved. When is the cashsale created - is it after the salesorder has been saved at least once? If done before then some fields you might expect to contain data will not.

Comment: Also why are you using to_date on a date value? In the workflow, after the record has been created, it will be a date value not a string.  For the before load you can assume the current time so `{sysdate}` should work

Comment: @Brian thanks for your input, my test case works on "Create" -> "Before Record Load" I have tested by clicking the "Bill" button on a Sales Order for both `to_date({createdfrom.datecreated}) + 1` and `{createdfrom.datecreated}` it works as expected, just the CASE statement doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @bknights thank you for your suggestion of just using `{createdfrom.datecreated}` instead of the to_date() function, you are absolutely right, a data does not need to be converted into a date. For some reason I have found I do still need to use `to_date({createdfrom.datecreated}) + 1` with adding a day to the date `{createdfrom.datecreated} + 1` generates an error

Comment: @bknights not sure I understand your comment about {sysdate} perhaps I am missing something there, as I want to get the date created of the parent sales order record and I am unsure how sysdate can do that for me.

Comment: Even tried as per SuiteAnswer ID#34539 checking checking "Home" -> "Set Preferences" -> "Date Format"

Which was set to: D/M/YYYY then tried `CASE WHEN to_number(to_char({createdfrom.datecreated}, 'HH24')) >= 22 THEN to_char(({createdfrom.datecreated} + 1), 'D/M/YYYY') ELSE to_char(({createdfrom.datecreated}), 'D/M/YYYY') END`

Same Error unfortunately.

Comment: On another note @Brian how do I evaluate if a field is set and has a value in a NetSuite CASE Statement, because if a record doesn't have a created from record that could be a fringe-case, I would think something along the lines of `CASE WHEN {createdfrom} IS NOT NULL THEN ... ELSE {today} END` e.g.  but that seems to produce an error even when I try it in a Saved Search. Just curious, I probably need to solve my first issue first.

Comment: @Brian possibly `CASE WHEN EXISTS({createdfrom}) ...` ? (doesn't seem to work for me either in a saved search, but might be something I am doing, just curious how you would approach it)

Comment: So you are using the result of the formula within a Set Value action to set the value of the "trandate" ? What error message are you getting ?

Comment: Hi @B.Assem, the error message I am getting is `Notice (SuiteScript)
 
You have entered an Invalid Field Value ERROR: Invalid Expression for the following field: trandate`

Comment: Hi @B.Assem, yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: So it looks like that the Case formula is returning a value not accepted by the Set Value action, in cases like this, I always try to see what is the real result of the Case formula by storing it in a workflow field, so you can try that using either a Text or Date field: there is a chance that the Case formula is returning an error or is returning a Text value.

Comment: Also, one possible error in your case is the formatting: for example, extra spaces can generate errors because formula are interpreted as Oracle queries. For example, change to_number(to_char({createdfrom.datecreated}, 'HH24')) to to_number(to_char({createdfrom.datecreated},'HH24'))

Comment: Thanks @B.Assem and bknights these are great troubleshooting suggestions, I will remove spaces and try writing the result of the case statement to a notes / memo field or a custom text field and report back to you on what I find.

Comment: I put this down yesterday as I just keep going around in circles and making no progress, but I will come back to it later today and try some troubleshooting tips from @B.Assem

Comment: In fact, I did some tests myself, and I can confirm that the Case state is returing an error and the error is mainly related to any Function applied on {createdfrom.datecreated} : not sure why, but it looks like that "statement" is not returning a DATE, so the to_char will fail. I also tried to consider it as a string and convert it to a DATE, but TO_DATE failed too... So, I think you have two options here:
1. Contact Netsuite Support.
2. Do what you want to do using a Custom Workflow Action.

Comment: Thanks @B.Assem, I will log a ticket with NetSuite as the logical evaluation should have nothing to do with the data being written to the date field. As we have clearly seen `to_date({createdfrom.datecreated}) + 1` and `{createdfrom.datecreated}` work individually and only fail in the case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Netsuite Workflow formula value is not reliable in terms of using the Netsuite formulas that run in saved search. Some work and some don’t. In this case the To_char and date formatting seems to be not recognized at all.

Solution is a custom field named “Created Hours” that is dynamically sourcing value from a saved search.  The field is exposed in Sales Order and Cash Sale transaction form (You can hide it as well). I then use the field as my comparison to achieve the condition that will set the date value. I tested few old Sales orders converting to Cash Sales and works well

[Custom field hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLrmB.png)

[Hours saved search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQRCD.png)

[Workflow to evaluate hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ4vr.png)

Hope this helps other people with the same or similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

so basically in a before load create record user event use:

```sql
CASE WHEN to_number(to_char({sysdate}, 'HH24')) >= 22 THEN {sysdate} + 1 ELSE {sysdate} END
```

I see you have clarified your question.

`{trandate}` is a date field while the formula is producing a datetime field

So since your formula is meant to populate a date field you have to convert the datetime to a date:

```sql
TRUNC(CASE WHEN to_number(to_char({createdfrom.datecreated}, 'HH24')) >= 22 THEN {createdfrom.datecreated} + 1 ELSE {createdfrom.datecreated} END)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @bknights, I really appreciate your suggestions.

`{createdfrom.datecreated} + 1` 

Yields an error even if just entered on its own as the complete formula


`Notice (SuiteScript)
 
You have entered an Invalid Field Value ERROR: Invalid Expression for the following field: trandate`

This works on its own as a complete formula:

`to_date({createdfrom.datecreated}) + 1`

Comment: I tried your formula above using {sysdate} I get an error unfortunately 

`
Notice (SuiteScript)
 
You have entered an Invalid Field Value ERROR: Field 'sysdate' Not Found for the following field: trandate`

Comment: @bkknights thanks for continuing to help me, `Notice (SuiteScript)
 
You have entered an Invalid Field Value ERROR: Invalid Expression for the following field: trandate` is the error message generated by `TRUNC(CASE WHEN to_number(to_char({createdfrom.datecreated}, 'HH24')) >= 22 THEN {createdfrom.datecreated} + 1 ELSE {createdfrom.datecreated} END)` so didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Wow that's maddening. I tried recreating what I think your workflow is doing.
Just making the formula `{createdfrom.datecreated}` works. `NEXT_DAY({createdfrom.datecreated})+1` works but isn't the number you are looking for.  Various forms of casting the result do not work either.

Comment: I know right, logically this should be very simple and setting the values on their own works, it just doesn't work in a case statement, agreed completely maddening LOL :)